# XSD.EXE throws errors on an XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

XSD.exe gives me an error saying

**Error: Error generating classes for schema 'POCD_MT000001UK04'.
  - The element 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:messageType' is missing.**

Here are all the errors XSD.exe gives me:

Schema validation warning: Reference to undeclared model group 'xhtml:NPfIT:Pres
entationText:htmlRoot'. Line 270, position 10.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 1020, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 976, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 951, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 940, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 926, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 914, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 903, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 869, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 819, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 806, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 746, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 732, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 587, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 573, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:recipientRoleCode' elemen
t is not declared. Line 534, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 523, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 512, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 497, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 448, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 428, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 403, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 352, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 326, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 303, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 279, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 267, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 245, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 233, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 219, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 208, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:messageType' element is n
ot declared. Line 176, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 149, position 5.
Schema validation warning: The 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:contentId' element is not
 declared. Line 136, position 5.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce
 incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'POCD_MT000001UK04'.
  - The element 'NPFIT:HL7:Localisation:messageType' is missing.

I am calling XSD.exe blah.XSD /classes /language:C#

this has worked for me on another XSD but not one that does an import like this XSD.

Note it gives other warnings saying other NPFIT data types aren't defined (like contentID)

The XSD I have refers to other XSD files which seem to work fine, it is just the NPFIT one that is a problem.  I notice the main difference is it is referenced by an import statement vs. an include.

The NPFIT xsd is present. In case it was somehow having issues doing path navigation (even though it is remote case given the include files could be reache din another directory) I moved the file into the same folder as the POCD message and changed the reference in the XSD and it still gives same issue.

Note I loaded the XSD into VS2013 to see if it would validate and it did load it but gave some warnings. Not the same messages I got with XSD.exe but were related to the NPFIT elements.  It did read the NPFIT file as I can see those elements show up in the XML tree.

Here is the main XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:npfitlc="NPFIT:HL7:Localisation"
           targetNamespace="urn:hl7-org:v3"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
           <xs:include schemaLocation="../dt/infrastructureRoot.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../VocabularySchemas/CDAVocab.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../dt/datatypeflavours.xsd"/>
   <xs:import namespace="NPFIT:HL7:Localisation" schemaLocation="../dt/NHSLocalisation.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../TemplateSchemas/NPFIT-000014_Role.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../TemplateSchemas/NPFIT-000008_Role.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../TemplateSchemas/NPFIT-000007_Role.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../TemplateSchemas/NPFIT-000019_Role.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../TemplateSchemas/NPFIT-000001_Section.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../TemplateSchemas/NPFIT-000041_Section.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../TemplateSchemas/NPFIT-000032_Section.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../TemplateSchemas/NPFIT-000024_Role.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../TemplateSchemas/NPFIT-000016_Role.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="../TemplateSchemas/NPFIT-000001_Act.xsd"/>
   <xs:element name="ClinicalDocument" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.ClinicalDocument"/>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.Authenticator">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="signatureCode" type="CS" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="time" type="TS" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000024_Role"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="AUTHEN"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.Author">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="functionCode" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:complexContent>
                  <xs:restriction base="CV">
                     <xs:attribute name="code" use="required" fixed="OA" type="cs"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="displayName" use="required" fixed="Originating Author" type="st"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="codeSystem" use="required" fixed="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.17.178"
                                   type="uid"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="codeSystemName" type="st" use="prohibited"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="codeSystemVersion" type="st" use="prohibited"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="updateMode" type="cs" use="prohibited"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="cs_NullFlavor" use="prohibited"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
               </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="time" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:complexContent>
                  <xs:restriction base="TS">
                     <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="ts"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="updateMode" type="cs" use="prohibited"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="cs_NullFlavor" use="prohibited"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
               </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000007_Role"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="AUT"/>
      <xs:attribute name="contextControlCode" type="ContextControl" use="required" fixed="OP"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.ClassificationSection">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element name="id" type="II.NPfIT.uuid.mandatory" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="component" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component3" minOccurs="1"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="entry" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component_1" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="entry1" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component2_1" nillable="true"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="classCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="DOCSECT"/>
      <xs:attribute name="moodCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="EVN"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.ClinicalDocument.typeId">
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:restriction base="II">
            <xs:attribute name="root" type="uid" fixed="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="extension" use="required">
               <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="st">
                     <xs:enumeration value="POCD_HD000040"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
               </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="cs_NullFlavor" use="prohibited"/>
            <xs:attribute name="updateMode" type="cs_UpdateMode" use="prohibited"/>
            <xs:attribute name="assigningAuthorityName" type="st" use="prohibited"/>
            <xs:attribute name="displayable" type="bl" use="prohibited"/>
         </xs:restriction>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.ClinicalDocument">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element name="code" type="CV.NPfIT.CodedCodeSystem.required" minOccurs="1"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="confidentialityCode" type="CE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="effectiveTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:complexContent>
                  <xs:restriction base="TS">
                     <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="ts"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="updateMode" type="cs" use="prohibited"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="cs_NullFlavor" use="prohibited"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
               </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="id" type="II.NPfIT.uuid.mandatory" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:messageType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="setId" type="II.NPfIT.uuid.mandatory" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="title" type="ST" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="typeId" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.ClinicalDocument.typeId" minOccurs="1"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="versionNumber" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:complexContent>
                  <xs:restriction base="INT">
                     <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="int"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="updateMode" type="cs" use="prohibited"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="cs_NullFlavor" use="prohibited"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
               </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="authenticator" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.Authenticator" nillable="true"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="author" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.Author" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="component" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component2" minOccurs="1"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="componentOf" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component" minOccurs="1"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="custodian" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.Custodian" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="dataEnterer" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.DataEnterer" nillable="true"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="informationRecipient"
                     type="POCD_MT030001UK01.PrimaryInformationRecipient"
                     minOccurs="1"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="recordTarget" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.RecordTarget" minOccurs="1"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="relatedDocument" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.ReplacementOf" nillable="true"
                     minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="tracker" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.Tracker" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="classCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="DOCCLIN"/>
      <xs:attribute name="moodCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="EVN"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000001_Act"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="COMP"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component_1">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000041_Section"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="COMP"/>
      <xs:attribute name="contextConductionInd" type="bl" use="required" fixed="true"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component2">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="structuredBody" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.StructuredBody" minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="nonXMLBody" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.NonXMLBody" minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="COMP"/>
      <xs:attribute name="contextConductionInd" type="bl" use="required" fixed="true"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component2_1">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000032_Section"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="COMP"/>
      <xs:attribute name="contextConductionInd" type="bl" use="required" fixed="true"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component3">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000001_Section"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="COMP"/>
      <xs:attribute name="contextConductionInd" type="bl" use="required" fixed="true"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component5">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element name="classificationSection" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.ClassificationSection"
                     minOccurs="1"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="COMP"/>
      <xs:attribute name="contextConductionInd" type="bl" use="required" fixed="true"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.Custodian">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000014_Role"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="CST"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.DataEnterer">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000016_Role"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="ENT"/>
      <xs:attribute name="contextControlCode" type="ContextControl" use="required" fixed="OP"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.NonXMLBody">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element name="text" type="ED.NHS.NonXMLBodyText" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="classCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="DOCBODY"/>
      <xs:attribute name="moodCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="EVN"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.ParentDocument">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element name="code" type="CV" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="id" type="II.NPfIT.uuid.mandatory" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="setId" type="II.NPfIT.uuid.mandatory" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="versionNumber" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:complexContent>
                  <xs:restriction base="INT">
                     <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="int"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="updateMode" type="cs" use="prohibited"/>
                     <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="cs_NullFlavor" use="prohibited"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
               </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="classCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="DOCCLIN"/>
      <xs:attribute name="moodCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="EVN"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.PrimaryInformationRecipient">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000008_Role"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="PRCP"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.RecordTarget">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000019_Role"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="RCT"/>
      <xs:attribute name="contextControlCode" type="ContextControl" use="required" fixed="OP"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.ReplacementOf">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element name="priorParentDocument" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.ParentDocument"
                     nillable="true"
                     minOccurs="1"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="RPLC"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.StructuredBody">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element name="component" type="POCD_MT030001UK01.Component5" minOccurs="1"
                     maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="classCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="DOCBODY"/>
      <xs:attribute name="moodCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="EVN"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="POCD_MT030001UK01.Tracker">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
         <xs:element ref="npfitlc:contentId" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="NPFIT-000008_Role"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
      <xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="required" fixed="TRC"/>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is the XSD for the NPFIT schema that is imported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="NPFIT:HL7:Localisation" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3" targetNamespace="NPFIT:HL7:Localisation" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="urn:hl7-org:v3" schemaLocation="datatypes.xsd"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="content.root">
        <xs:restriction base="hl7:uid">
            <xs:pattern value="([0-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9][0-9]*)*">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>
                        Pattern facet to carry only oid in root of an II data type
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:pattern>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="content.extension">
        <xs:restriction base="hl7:st"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="content.oid">
        <xs:restriction base="content.root">
            <xs:enumeration value="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.16"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="Template.Content">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="hl7:II">
                <xs:attribute name="root" type="content.oid" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="extension" type="content.extension" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="hl7:cs_NullFlavor" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="updateMode" type="hl7:cs_UpdateMode" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="assigningAuthorityName" type="hl7:st" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="displayable" type="hl7:bl" use="prohibited"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="messagetype.root">
        <xs:restriction base="hl7:uid">
            <xs:pattern value="([0-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9][0-9]*)*">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>
                        Pattern facet to carry only oid in root of an II data type
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:pattern>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="messagetype.extension">
        <xs:restriction base="hl7:st"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="message.type.oid">
        <xs:restriction base="messagetype.root">
            <xs:enumeration value="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.17"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="Message.Type">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="hl7:II">
                <xs:attribute name="root" type="messagetype.root" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="extension" type="messagetype.extension" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="hl7:cs_NullFlavor" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="updateMode" type="hl7:cs_UpdateMode" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="assigningAuthorityName" type="hl7:st" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="displayable" type="hl7:bl" use="prohibited"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="contentId" type="Template.Content"/>
    <xs:element name="messageType" type="Message.Type"/>
    <xs:element name="recipientRoleCode" type="hl7:CV"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Should `message.type.oid` be `messagetype.oid`?

Comment: That does seem off but when I changed it, I still got errors.  I only provided one of the errors as I figure they were indicative but here is the entire error output added to initial post.

Comment: I really think the issue has to somehow be related to the import (vs. include) failing.